# jQuery each only recognizing first element that was clicked

Tags: jquery, html

My problem is fairly basic (at least, for you guys), but I can't seem to get it work.

So I have products and an add to cart button. I need it so that whenever I add a product already in the cart, it will not add it in a new line, but rather, just increase the count.

Somehow, it only recognizes the first product that was clicked. Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/78wUa/

```
var initial = 0;
jQuery('.add-to-cart').live('click', function() {
    jQuery('.no-prods').fadeOut();
    jQuery('.subtotal').fadeIn();

    var dataOwner = jQuery(this).parent().closest('div').attr('data-owner');
    var dataClass = jQuery(this).parent().closest('div').attr('data-owner');
    dataClass = '.' + dataClass;

    var count = '<span class="prod-count ' + dataOwner + '">' + 1 + '</span>';

    var price = jQuery(this).parent().closest('div').attr('data-price');
    price = 'jQuery<span class="prod-price">' + price + '</span>';

    if(initial == 0) {
        var p_name = jQuery('.span9 ' + dataClass + ' h3').clone();
        var p_name_and_quantity = jQuery(p_name).after(' ' + count + ' x ' + price);
        jQuery('.my-cart').append(p_name_and_quantity);
        initial = 1;
        //get_subtotal();
    } else {
        get_products(dataClass, count, price);
    }
});

function get_products(dataClass, count, price) {
    jQuery('.my-cart h3').each(function() {
        var c_name = jQuery(this).html();
        var product = jQuery('.span9 ' + dataClass + ' h3').html();
        if(c_name == product) {
            //get_count(count, dataClass);
            return false;
        } else {
            var this_p_name = jQuery('.span9 ' + dataClass + ' h3').clone();
            var this_p_name_and_quantity = jQuery(this_p_name).after(' ' + count + ' x ' + price);
            jQuery('.my-cart').append(this_p_name_and_quantity);
            get_subtotal();
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Where is your get_subtotal function?

Comment: First of all - classes have to start with a letter, so class "0001" is likely not to work correctly

Comment: Lian, it's a concern as of this moment. That's why I commented it out. Asped, okay thanks. I will change them.

Comment: @user2772219, what I meant was that it isn't defined, therefore I cannot tell how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I have updated your code and made it in my own way:-  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78wUa/6/)

```
function get_products(el) {
    if(products.indexOf($(el).attr('data-product')) == -1){
         products.push($(el).attr('data-product'))
      $('.my-cart').append('<h3 class="product">' +             $(el).parent().find("h3").html() + '</h3>');
    }
    subTotal += +$(el).parent().attr("data-price");
    $(".subtotal").html("Subtotal: $" + subTotal);
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.